# Re-writing URL parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, query-string

So I have a script (written in PHP) that posts the user input of a reference number and postcode and then redirects the user to a page with the URL parameters like so:

> http://mydomain.com/data.php?reference=REF1234&postcode=LE1FEH

The data.php script will then fetch the data from the database according to the URL parameters, now I want to hide the paramaters from the user's view - both to prevent SQL injections and to make the URL simpler. I don't want to directly hide the inputted data in the URL. Apple seem to be the only place I can find who do it like this right now - in their URL you are able to see an order number and postcode but no equals sign or anything, like so:

> https://store.apple.com/uk/order/guest/ordernumber/postcode

Is there anyway of going about doing this?

(I'm not sure if you would class this as encryption or what not, so I had a hard time finding any useful articles on this as well as wording it well - so i'm sorry if it is a little confusing)

Comment: URL Rewriting.  Search for that term and you'll find what you need instantly.

Comment: @user1013930: Also, you can just set your forms to method="POST" to 'hide' the URL from the user, but anyone with FireBug can just edit the HTML and send you an injection payload. Your only option, regardless of what else you do, is to sanitize your user's input. Period. Don't trust them ever!

Comment: The form's method is actually POST however I send the user to the page from the form like so: header('Location: data.php?reference='.$reference'&postcode='.$postcode); So I don't really understand what you mean when you say it 'hides' the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)$ ./data.php?reference=$1&postcode=$2 [NC]
```

Your URL http://mydomain.com/REF1234/LE1FEH will treated as http://mydomain.com/data.php?reference=REF1234&postcode=LE1FEH and you can get the values by GET method.

For more [info](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` to do this. However bear in mind that it is just as vulnerable to SQL injections as "normal" URLs, and more prone to internal server errors at the tiniest fault. Personally I would advise against this method unless it's likely users will want to easily share URLs, but regardless of what you choose to do, make sure you guard against injections at all times.

Comment: Note this is Apache specific. There are generally URL rewriting options for other web servers. Also, you don't need to use `.htaccess`. In fact, placing rewriting rules in your server config is much more preferable